# Error 403 accessDenied when trying to access SharePoint sharing link via API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Our application is using SharePoint to upload files from our server, which the external user can then access.

Can somebody help us out?

1. To create the sharing link (type edit, scope users), we followed the instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), which worked fine
2. We grant the user permissions for this link (write), following the instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), which worked fine
3. Using the `GET /drive/items/{item-id}/permissions` endpoint, we verified the user is shown under `grantedToIdentitiesV2` and `grantedToIdentities`, which worked fine
4. Using the user's account, we send a request to `GET /shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}`, which is erroring with the following message

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "The sharing link no longer exists, or you do not have permission to access it.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-12-05T12:22:19",
            "request-id": "xxx",
            "client-request-id": "yyy"
        }
    }
}
```

If the user instead opens the link in their browser, they can access the files just fine. We expected the call to the API to work just fine as well.

The encoded sharing url is correct, all required scopes are present, we also tried specifying the `Prefer` header. We repeated all steps on the Graph Explorer. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: does it work? how your issue was solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can open it directly without visiting link just add header Prefer with value redeemSharingLink to

request [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{{base64ShareURI}}/driveItem](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/%7B%7Bbase64ShareURI%7D%7D/driveItem).

[image]

Doc Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: Unfortunately we already tried setting the Prefer header. It didn't work either.

Comment: Okay , if that's fine ,then could you please confirm if you have Files.ReadWrite.All or Sites.ReadWrite.All application permission ?

Comment: Yes. We gave Graph Explorer all permissions possible, including Files.ReadWrite.All and Sites.ReadWrite.All.

Comment: Please check these 2 doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/access-denied-or-need-permission-error-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive-for-business and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/access-denied-to-pim-user-accounts

Comment: We tried sharing a file instead of a folder, we tried adding the user via PIM (which we don't want to do anyway), and I quintuple checked the permissions. It is still throwing the error.
It should be noted again that the website works without issues, only the API has errors.

Comment: Could you please help us to understand , as you said website works fine , are you taking about SharePoint webapp?

Comment: I mean that when the user clicks on the sharing link, e.g. `test.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/TestWebsite/EU-hjkluYh...`
everything works. SharePoint opens in their browser and they have access to the file/folder.

But if we, as the user, send a request to e.g. `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0c...`
we receive the error.

Comment: Thanks for the update , could you please provide latest request id and timestamp for the error .

Comment: "date": "2022-12-08T11:45:03",
"request-id": "e330dcf9-5997-4cd6-928c-1138edd86b09",
"client-request-id": "43d39c63-e6a4-05bc-9578-f883bf9196b0"

Comment: How are you getting the access token?

Comment: In this case, I only used the Graph Explorer. So Graph Explorer is generating and using it.

Comment: In this case could you please try providing delegated permission for Files.ReadWrite.All or Sites.ReadWrite.All .

Comment: I already gave Graph Explorer these permissions. There are no more permissions it asks of me.

Comment: Could you please help me to understand ,are you trying this on graph explorer or in you application , because both need different permission (delegated / application), if you are trying in graph explorer , this should work with delegate permission , but when you are trying in your Application you need application permission . you can also check the list of permission in azure portal . Thanks

Comment: I am trying this in Graph Explorer, to eliminate potential errors on our side.